# Flash AS3 removeEventListener not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addeventlistener

I have 4 movie clips on my main timeline that I am adding event listeners to:

```
answerAmc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerA);
answerBmc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerB);
answerCmc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerC);
answerDmc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerD);
```

Then a few frames later I'm trying to remove the event listeners:

```
answerAmc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerA);
answerBmc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerB);
answerCmc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerC);
answerDmc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, processAnswerD);
```

But the movie clips are still click-able, and still fire off the processAnswerX functions.

I've made this as basic as possible, but it seems my removeEventListener just aren't working?  Am I missing something that might be right in front of my face?

Comment: Your code seems to work. Share us some more details.

Comment: can you post your .fla?   coding things on frames has lots of nuances.  like keyframes changing references to objects etc

Comment: Ok, I've thrown the test file up at http://ixsweb.com/test.fla.  What I'm trying to accomplish here is if someone clicks on answer A within frames 15-110 the processAnswerA function will be called.   The correct answer within those frames should be "C".  However, once you get to frame 111, a new set of questions will be asked, and the correct answer should be "D".  Currently, the correct answer always stays as "C", even though I am removing the listener and re-adding.  If I should be doing this a better way, please let me know.

Comment: try mouseChildren = false; for their parents